# Is it possible to use Nokia c5-03 phone as wifi router?

Tags: wireless-networking, phone

Can you tell me is it possible to connect

`Desktop Computer --> Phone --> Notebook`

by using Cell Phone as Wi Fi router.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the keyword is "tethering". Go to Wireless and networking settings, choose "Tethering and hotsopt" and then enable Mobile AP. Connect both computer and laptop to this wifi - they will see each other. Most probably.